# Styling Checkbox in PrimeNG

Tags: typescript, primeng

I am trying to change the following PrimeNG checkbox label styling (i.e. Font Size):

```
<div class="ui-g-7">
    <p-checkbox name="group1" value="Los Angeles" label="Los Angeles" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities" inputId="la">
    </p-checkbox>
</div>
```

I found the `labelStyleClass`in documentation which is the Style class of the label. But I could not use it. Any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply achieve this in your `.css` or `.scss` file

```
:host::ng-deep {
    .ui-chkbox-label {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
```

**Note:** If you have not enabled viewEncapsulation in your component. Then use `:host::ng-deep`. It is highly recommended.

Output:

[image]

Also for your convenience have created functional example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tdkc3d

Hope it will help.

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code

```
:host::ng-deep ui-chkbox-label {
   color: blue;
}
```

You can use `:host::ng-deep` with any of the classes as mentioned in the image [image: here]